# SaveState exception: Cannot Create file, Operation not permitted

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I test SaveState on my iPad, I follow exactly the same logic on the [embarcadero SaveState example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/FireMonkey_Save_State), but it throws an exception after saving data.

However, the same logic tested on iOS Simulator is working fine.
I am using Delphi 10.3.1 with an iPad iOS12.2

When I click the home button after the FormSaveState logic executed, the below exception occurred:
Cannot create file ....... Operation not permitted
[image: the exception]

The same logic tested on iOS Simulator is working fine.
Any idea why this occurred and how to resolve? Thanks for any help!

Comment: The raised exception clearly states what the problem is. You are trying to create a new file in a folder where you don't have sufficient permissions to do so. Now I don't have much experience with iOS, but I assume your application would probably first need proper manifest file to tell the OS that it intends on writing data to disk. Also I'm pretty sure that you are somewhat limited of where you can write your data. For more information about this matter I'm afraid you will have to read some development documentation or guidelines for iOS operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
SaveState.StoragePath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetTempPath
```

and not

```
SaveState.StoragePath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath;
```

Comment: I tried GetCachePath and it works. That could be used for my app, since storing SaveState data in Cache path does make sense to me, thanks!