# Problem writing file on IOS in Firemonkey

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I have a login screen in our mobile app in Firemonkey.
I use the following routine to save the entered parameters and read them again when the user launches the application again.
The code works fine on Android, but in IOS I get an error that the directory does not exist.

```
procedure TLoginFrm.Save_login_parameters;
var SettingsIniFile: TMemIniFile;
    LDirectory:      string;
    LFileName:       string;
begin
  LDirectory := TPath.GetHomePath + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'Settings';
  TDirectory.CreateDirectory(LDirectory);
  LFileName := TPath.GetHomePath + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'Settings' + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'WaveDeskSettings.ini';
  SettingsIniFile := TMemIniFile.Create(LFileName);
  SettingsIniFile.WriteString('Login', 'Account', EditAccount.Text);
  SettingsIniFile.WriteString('Login', 'Login',   EditLogin.Text);
  SettingsIniFile.UpdateFile;
end;
```

Comment: At which point do you get the error. At the "CreateDirectory" point or the "UpdateFile" point (try omitting the part of the code that uses SettingsIniFile and see if you still get the error). Also, you should use _LDirectory := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath,'Settings');_ and _LFileName := TPath.Combine(LDirectory,'WaveDeskSettings.ini');_

Comment: Hi, I've changed the code, but I still have the problem. I get the error on the SettingsIniFile.UpdateFile. I have added a condition if TDirectory.Exists(LDirectory) but it seems the directory is not created, it always returns a file. Strange thing is that TDirectory.CreateDirectory does not return an error. I have no clue.

Comment: From what I can see in the runtime library source code, _TDirectory.CreateDirectory_ does not report any errors. You should use _ForceDirectories_ in System.SysUtils instead (it's a function that returns TRUE if the directory was created or already exists). If it is indeed that the directory isn't created, it's probably a rights issue. There may be a right you're not requesting in your manifest that's needed in order to create new directories in the Home Path on iOS. You could try it without a new sub directory (your Home Path is already application-specific, AFAIK).

Comment: It seems I don't have permissions to write in the Home Path also. ForeceDirectories returns False, also saving the file direct in the Home Path gives me an error with operation not permitted. I've found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583508/savestate-exception-cannot-create-file-operation-not-permitted, seems like writing in the Home Path is not permitted at all? Writing to Cache path works, but I don't know how long the data will persist in de cache directory.

Comment: I have been able to solve it using the GetLibraryPath. Apparently that directory is specific for storing data that needs to be persisted.